# Unable to login after deleting my home partition?

Tags: boot-failure, home-directory

I deleted my /home partition now I am unable to log on.  When I log on as Guest I get a blank desktop

Is it possible to fix this preferably without reinstalling?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do two things

1 Recreate /home and update /etc/fstab to mount it in the proper place

2 Recreate your /home/username folder by copying /etc/skel

#### Step 1

Boot a live disk (or your OS if you can) and create a filesystem where your /home partition used to be. Find the UUID of this partition by matching up it's entry in `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid` or by using `blkid`. Update the entry in `/etc/fstab` to match this new number.

#### Step 2

Also from the live environment, copy `/etc/skel` to your new home partition (after mounting it on say, `/mnt`) and rename it to your user's shortname. E.g., `cp -R /etc/skel /mnt/username`. Lastly, take ownership of everything in your homedir. This will be tricky as you don't know your numeric UID. Easy way is to make it all `chmod -R 777 /home/username/` and then `chown -R root:root /home/username` and then reboot to your resotred user account and do the same but with your username. You will have to redo all of your settings, but it is better than nothing.